# Why can keras not load RMSprop model (.h5)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I trained a keras model with optimizer `RMSprop` (let hypertuning determine the optimizer, and it chose that RMSprop is the best param). It trained without any issues. I wrote it to disk with `model.save(model_file)`, and also no issues.

Now, when attempting to load the model, I get a `ValueError`, and keras claims it does not understand the optimizer `RMSprop`. Models with `adam` work. What's going on here?

```
import keras
my_model = 'model_file.h5'
keras.models.load_model(my_model)
```

> ValueError: Unknown optimizer: Custom>RMSprop.

Comment: It might help if you showed how the model is being saved/compiled, outside of that one line?